# WORDPRESS How to add custom fields from taxonomy into a loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have a 3 custom post types created (Movies, Videos and Reviews) and 1 taxonomy (Artists).

I have a loop inside the single-movies.php and inside it shows some informations about the movie, all gathered from the post. Here's what I'm working on:

```
<section class="aboutmovie">
             <h1><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_titulobr_filme', true ); ?></h1>

                <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_poster_filme', true ); ?>">

                <h3><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_titulo_filme', true ); ?></h3>
                <span class="genero"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_genero_filme', true ); ?></span><br>
                <span class="ano"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_pais_filme', true ); ?>, <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ano_filme', true ); ?></span><br>
                <span class="dist"><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_distribuidora_filme', true ); ?></span><br>

                <span class="diretor"><b>Diretor:</b> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_diretor_filme', true ); ?></span><br>
                <span class="roteiro"><b>Roteiro:</b> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_roteiro_filme', true ); ?></span>
</section>
```

I need to add the CAST. For that I need the terms from that taxonomy (artists). I was able to show the list using this:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list(   
    $post->ID, 
    'artistas', 
    '<ul class="artistas"><li>', 
    ',</li><li>', 
    '</li></ul>' 
);  ?>
```

But I also need some information from the custom fields of those terms (term metas: nome and imagem). Basically I need to show an image (I have a custom field called "imagem" to add a link), the link to the artist page and his name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ul>
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'artistas', '<li class="artistas">', ', ', '</li>' ) ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: But that's the one I was already using. I need to include on the list the artist's picture, from the taxonomy's custom field

Comment: I've tried everything else :( This one is the only one that seems to work.